# Crystal Report - unable to use TEXT type as a parameter?

Tags: crystal-reports

I am currently developing a website, asp.net 4.0 using crystal reports, I can view the report perfectly etc, however when trying to create parameters in the report I am unable to select or even view `TEXT` type fields in my database table when selecting a field to create the parameter from.  Selecting string or integers etc work fine, but all `TEXT` type fields arent even visible.

Any ideas as to why this may be?  I need to add a parameter from a `TEXT` field as we want to limit the results to all messages which contain a certain phraze, and that message is stored in a sql database as a `TEXT` type.

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert Text type into varchar(max) and then it will be show.

Otherwise you have to add Custom Parameter field and read this value into the parameter and this parameter will drag on your report design page.

Comment: Would I do the conversion in a formula in crystal reports, if so could you provide a sample please?

Comment: in Crystal report Conversion formula is Cstr. but I think you required to change in your database select query or Stored procedure whatever you are using for that....

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a parameter that is a 'String' type.

Next, cast your TEXT value to different type using a SQL Expression:

```
//{%converted_text}
(
   cast( TEXT AS varchar2(255) )
)
```

You may need to adjust the syntax (I'm using Oracle's).

Finally, reference each in the record-selection formula:

```
{%converted_text} = {?text_prompt}
```